# reading data from ef relationship mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Am having challenge selecting data uisng LINQ to EF. I have two related models such as Category and Post.

I successful created the Category model and also the Post which is assigned to only one Category.

Here are the models:

```
    public class Menu
    {
        public int MenuId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Posts> Posts { get; set; }
        public string PostedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime PostedDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Posts
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }  
        public DateTime PostedDate { get; set; }

        public int MenuId { get; set; }
        public virtual Menu Menus{ get; set; }
    }
```

when reading the index page, I want the menu view to render post view as link and when the link is clicked it should direct to the post details.

Comment: Really. I want to win the Lottery when I buy a ticket...

Comment: please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've typed `Menu.Posts` as `List<Posts>`. In order to manage the relationship, EF needs it typed as `ICollection<Posts>`. If you use `List<Posts` as you've done, EF will ignore it entirely. It will not create the relationship in the database and it will not fill the property with the related entities or even add the lazy-loading logic necessary to pull them in later.

Also, FWIW, you should not name your classes (ever) or properties (unless they are a collection) as plurals. For example, `Posts`, should be `Post`, since an instance of `Post` is just one thing, not many. Likewise, with your `Menus` property, it just holds a single menu, not multiple.

Comment: thank you Chris Pratt. I got it all resolve with your reply.